# Displaying row colors in a NSOutlineView?

Tags: cocoa

How do I manage to display the rows color in a NSOutlineView, such as in a NSTableView by default ?

[image]

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want this in Your NSOutlineView You need to use ***Alternating Rows***.

You can change this in *Attributes inspector*:

[image]